# Confirmation Box in Java | Compilation Error

Tags: java, windows, cygwin

I'm a new programmer and I'm having issues when I compile the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.swing.*;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    int UserExit = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you really want to exit?", "Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (UserExit == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye!");
        }
        else {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Too late my friend!");
           System.exit(0);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I have checked it many times but cannot find the mistake. Cygwin doesn't show the mistake and blames something different every time.
I use cygwin as the compilation tool and my OS is Windows 8.1 x64 Bit.

Any help would be very welcome.

**EDIT** I use javac to compile code in Java, I meant I use cygwin as it's platform. I apologize.

**EDIT** The compiler was continiously "blaming" the libraries, the mistake was a wrongly typed class. Thanks to @kagmole and @RealSkeptic for helping me out :)

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't show the mistake"? It must print something. Please [edit] the question and add what the compiler is giving you. And Cygwin is a collection of tools. The appropriate tool to compile Java is `javac` (if you are not using an IDE, which you really should).

Comment: You are correct, I use mintty.exe from the cygwin tools and Java's IDE in my opinion is just a very, very bad tool. It has so many taskbars and buttons that drive me crazy. For me the old-fashioned gedit tool is good enough, such as it provides an environment where the user cannot get distracted.

Comment: Well, the next tool you'll need is a debugger. Running that from command-line is a nightmare. If you have toolbars that you don't need, you can remove them. And there is [a lange choice of many different IDEs](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/03/the-top-11-free-ide-for-java-coding-development-programming/). I don't know a single professional programmer who doesn't use an IDE for Java. Developing without one is simply not scalable.

Comment: Even though really easy to debug it from command-line, I agree with you because many times it gets tiring. I'm still very new in Java and programming, causing me asking questions that may seem ridiculous to others, such as the IDEs you mentioned above; I answered to you about a completely different thing, my apologizes. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `swing` components are inside `javax`, not `java`.

Correct your imports by:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; // <- Here
```

By the way, you should avoid global imports, and just import what you want like this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The code now runs smoothly :) Have an awesome day!